# convert a column to rows of value counts python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data like this

```
date            ordertype 
2013/10/10        B2B
2013/10/10        B2C
2013/10/10        B2B
```

expected output

```
date          B2B        B2C
2013/10/10    2           1
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['ordertype'])`

Comment: Or `df.value_counts().unstack('ordertype')`